# Specify "Left Detail" Table View Cell's Text

Tags: iphone, ios, uitableview, tableview

I have a UITableView with a "Left Detail" styled cell. The table view is static and has been created within a storyboard.  However, when I run the app, the left detail cell's text disappears.  So how can I specify the cell's main text and the small label next to it through code?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do you still have the `UITableViewDataSource` methods implemented? If you're using a static table, you should remove those because they're going to overwrite what you've set in the storyboard.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion.  No, I took out those methods. My main question is, how do I set either label in the cell's left detail view programatically?

Comment: With `textLabel` or `detailTextLabel` respectively. That will return the instance of `UILabel`. Set the `text` property on each `UILabel`.

Comment: Thank you, I just realized I do have one UITableDataSourceMethod still implemented.  I'll convert the table to prototype cells and should be good. Thanks a lot.